# How do I delete a list view via the SharePoint API?

Tags: sharepoint

Seems simple enough, but there doesn't seem to be a delete method on the SPList object to remove a view, or a Delete() method on the SPView item itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Views property of the SPList returns a SPViewCollection which has a Delete method which takes the Id of the View as parameter

Note that SPList.Update() is not needed

Answer (score 0):

```
   for (int i = list.Views.Count; i > 0; i-- )
   {
       list.Views.Delete(listTo.Views[i].ID);
   }
```